# How to connect login model and post model

Tags: django

I have created a login and signup model also a post model in which a user can post the title and description. But when I login with a user and create a post then that post is also viewed by other user also.

I am using Django(python) with database sql.

For sign up form :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
    model = get_user_model()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["username"].label = "Display name"
    self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"
```

url.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
url(r"login/$",auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
url(r"logout/$", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
url(r"signup/$", views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
]
```

How can I limit my post to that specific user?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :) first please provide your `views.py` and `models.py` for posts too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its simple. You need to define a relation between post model and user model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # rest of the fields
```

Now in the Post Create View, you can do it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And finally in ListView, you need to define the queryset like this:

```
class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PostCreateView).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a concept called **Authorization**. you need to check authorization of your users on access to posts, so each user only sees his posts.

- First of all save `user` beside `post` model on each instance (using `ForeignKey`). So that each post has a `user` assigned to it.
- Now on accessing posts view with each user check if the user is authenticated, if so, then check if this user is the owner of that post or not, if not then give 403 permission denied error to him.

For example if your `Post` model is like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.CharFie.........
    .....
```

Then on each request to access a post, check if user is allowed to see it or not:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)    # For example you want to check post with id of 1
if post.user.id == request.user.id:
    # Then allow user to see it,
else:
    # Raise error 403
```

**Note:** Also add `login_required` decorator before post views. or `IsAuthenticated` permission class if you are using **CBV**.